# New-AzureRmEventHub gives error in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to run a PowerShell script, and it has an error on this line:

`$eventHub = New-AzureRmEventHub -ResourceGroupName $eventHubConfig.resourceGroupName -NamespaceName $eventHubConfig.namespace -Location $location -EventHubName $hubConfig.Value.name`

The error is this:

> New-AzureRmEventHub : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the
>   specified named parameters. At
>   C:\Users\David\Documents\EnvScripts\Components\EventHubs.ps1:108
>   char:16
>   + ... $eventHub = New-AzureRmEventHub -ResourceGroupName $eventHubConfig.re ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-AzureRmEventHub], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.EventHub.Commands.EventHub.NewAzureRmEven
>   tHub

The parameters that I am passing are these values:

`eventHubConfig.resourceGroupName: MyApp_David
eventHubConfig.namespace: myapp-eventhub-david
location: Canada East
hubConfig.Value.name: myapp-user-position-transactions-Debug`

I run this script on my colleagues environment and he doesn't have this problem...am I missing a PowerShell module? I installed and imported `AzureRM` in my PowerShell.

Comment: What is your Azure PowerShell version? `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` using the cmdlet check it.

Comment: Azure version 2.1.0

Comment: This is a older version. When you add `-MessageRetentionInDays 3`, do you fix this issue?

Comment: I test in my lab, I get the same error log with you. I add `-MessageRetentionInDays 3`, I fix this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use your command in my lab, I met the same error log with you. My Azure Power Shell version is 4.3.1.

I solve this issue when I add `-MessageRetentionInDays 3`.

[image]

More information please refer to this [link:Use PowerShell to manage Event Hubs resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-manage-with-ps).

Comment: Yes this solved it. Although my script is still giving errors for other commands, it's probably the same reason and have to add missing attributes. Weird that it works on my colleague's machine though. How do I update my version of Azure PowerShell to 4.3.1 ?

Comment: @Darius You could download msi and install it from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases).

Comment: Ok thanks. I did. I just feel awkward now since Felipe Binotto answered first but I wasn't at my office to test it...sorry Felipe... +1 for you too.. :/

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the namespace already exists and you use -MessageRetentionInDays and -PartitionCount parameters. Even though the documentation say they are not required, they seem to be.

Answer (score 0):

upgrading the AzureRM module should solve this issue. link to get latest AzureRM module https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureRM/6.5.0